# Find $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^2+5n^3}{2n^3+3\sqrt{4+n^6}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

$$\frac{n^2+5n^3}{2n^3+3\sqrt{4+n^6}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{n}+5}{2+\frac{3}{n^3}\sqrt{4+n^6}}$$
$$=\frac{\frac{1}{n}+5}{2+3\sqrt{\frac{4+n^6}{n^9}}}$$
$$=\frac{0+5}{2+0}$$
$$=\frac{5}{2}$$

...but the given answer is $1$. Where did I make a mistake??

Comment: $\sqrt{n^9}\neq n^3$.

Comment: I would try to rationalize the denominator first

Comment: @symplectomorphic Lol...woops. Thanks!

Comment: By looking at the term with highest exponent (since $n\to \infty$) we get $\frac{5n^3}{2n^3+3n^3}=1$

Answer (score 1):

The error is that you used $n^3=\sqrt{n^9}$. But...

Comment: $n^3*n^3$ = "Same base? Add the exponents." $=n^6$ <-- that's what I forgot....

Answer (score 0):

In your answer, the term under the radical $\sqrt{4+n^6}$ does not play a real role anymore. Since this is potentially the "most complicated term", this situation is an hint (not a proof) that something has gone wrong with your proof. The exercise as lost most of its interest to test your skill.

If you  factor your expression correctly with the term in $n$ with the highest power, you get: 
$$\frac{n^2+5n^3}{2n^3+3\sqrt{4+n^6}} = \frac{5n^3 \left(1+\frac{1}{5n}\right)}{2n^3+3n^3\sqrt{4/n^6+1}} = \frac{5n^3 \left(1+\frac{1}{5n}\right)}{n^3 (2+3\sqrt{4/n^6+1})}\,.$$

As for the notations, it is discouraged (even wrong) to write something like $\frac{1/n+5}{2+3/n} = \frac{5}{2}$, because it is not true. At the last stages, you should reintroduce the notion of limits, instead of writing a series of equalities.